# How to fix Summernote issue in my .Net 5 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, summernote

I am trying to use summernote on my contact form for the text area, and unfortunately I have the textarea showing twice int he contact form when running the application.
**Here is the textarea bootstrap code:**

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
             <label asp-for="Message">Message</label>
             <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" asp-for="Message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
             <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        //Default font size but not for placeholder...
        $('#Message').summernote({
            placeholder: "Please enter a message"
        });
    </script>
}
```

Note that I am using **"summernote-bs4.min.css"** & **"summernote-bs4.min.js"**

Comment: Hi @fyardlest, could you please share more view code? I test your provided code and the textarea only display once. Besides, what does your view look like?

Comment: Hello @Rena and thank you for answering. I think I got what was appening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for Bootstrap 4 I have to use the popper script to make it wor properly;

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
```